# How do I center the digits on a disabled input type="time" element?

Tags: javascript, html, input, time, center

How do I center the digits on a disabled input type="time" element?

Here's an example of a disabled time element that can't be centered because other hidden elements are taking the extra space :

```
jsfiddle.net/b4q679ha/1/
```

How can I disable these elements, or style it so it won't matter?

Comment: Only the "left" and "right" values of the align attribute work properly in all major browsers.
Then the align attribute is only used with <input type="image"> and it specifies the alignment of the image input according to surrounding elements.
The best solution should be replace your disabled input fields with `DIV` or `SPAN` and via Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in center using padding-left of CSS. Actually it is in center but top-down arrow creates the appearance issue.

Comment: That's a good CSS solution. As long as the parent's width is defined. Otherwise the change will increase the element's width.

Comment: In that case you can set margin-bottom in minus value. There is always a way. :)

Answer (score 1):

you are using input type time you can use normal input type text then its work

```
<input type="text" id="timeObj"/>
```

Or you can use in css

```
#timeObj{

padding-left:22px;
```

}